# How to get consistent return type from pandas indexers?

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"a":[11, 11, 22],
    },
    index = [1,1,2]
)

print type(df.loc[1,"a"])
print type(df.loc[2,"a"])
```

Which gets:

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<type 'numpy.int64'>
```

... meaning that the caller has to (always, always!) check whether the result is a value of a collection. This smells like a terrible design error.

Is there an indexer that always gives back a collection, so that I can write safe programs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass a collection:

```
print(type(df.loc[[2],"a"]))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```